# Custom title on JOptionPane message dialogs

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, title, joptionpane

When working with JOptionPane in Java, how do I make a custom title on a message dialog? I currently have:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You won the game in " + tries + " tries!");
```

I tried to add another parameter, and it gave me an error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16):

Try this

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You won the game in 7 tries!", "my title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

You need to supply the message type (4th param) so swing know which default icon to display.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the correct syntax for a dialog with a title:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is the message", "This is the title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
//                          Component; Text to appear in window; Title;            This is the type of dialog (can be error, as well)
```

Notice that there are **four** parameters, not three (there isn't a method with three parameters, as @Sanjay explained)

Answer (score 4):

In case thoughts fail, we have [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) to refer, which says,

```
showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent,
                     Object message,
                     String title,
                     int messageType)
```

Btw, your thought was right :) but note ,

1. There is no method with three parameters, **but it have four parameter and yes the third one is the title** for the dialog as String.
2. The parameters are not separated by `+` but by `,`

Answer (score 0):

I tried it this way:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,message,title, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

where

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
String message = "Population: "
String title = "City Info:"
JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE is messageType
```